# Use trigger to act as foreign key across 2 different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to replicate a foreign key across two servers using trigger. I know using trigger across 2 servers is not the best practice but my company on gives me read-only access to their database which I need to relate to my application.

I have DB1 which is my local database and it is attached to DB2 using linked server. I want trigger to check if a specific ID from a DB2_table on DB2 exists before executing an INSERT on DB1_table where the ID from DB2_table will act as a foreign key.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_DB1_Table_Insert
   @ID
BEFORE INSERT ON DB1_Table
AS
BEGIN
   if exists(Select ID from DB2_Table where ID = @ID)
   --execute insert 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually recommend using a check constraint instead of a trigger.  Check Constraints are designed to enforce data integrity and are a semantically better option.  The example below creates some working tables, then creates a function which will check if the record exists in the other table.

The check constraint then uses the function and returns an error if the value doesn't exist.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.OtherTable(
    id              INT 
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.a(
    id              INT     IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,OtherTableId   INT
)

GO


INSERT INTO OtherTable (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3)
GO


-- Function will check if the ID exists in the other table
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckOtherTableId(
     @OtherTableId          INT
)
RETURNS BIT 
AS BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS 
                    (
                        SELECT  1
                        FROM    OtherTable
                        WHERE   id = @OtherTableId
                    )
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
            END
    )
END
GO


-- Add check constraint
ALTER TABLE a  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_OtherTable] CHECK  (1=dbo.CheckOtherTableId(OtherTableId))
GO

-- Test should work
INSERT INTO a (OtherTableId) values (1)
Go

-- Test should fail
INSERT INTO a (OtherTableId) values (8)
GO
```